# Python - Differential equation, initial condition problem

Tags: python, differential-equations

I am trying to implement a function that controls the differential equation.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on when *exactly* do you want Qout to = 2? Is it only after yrez reaches exactly 5? Or as long as yrez >= 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you have to use a so called [finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). This basically means you have to store a state which can change depending on the input, and affects the output.

In this case:

```
#State variable
qout_state = 0

def Qout(yrez):
    #Declare that we will be using the global variable
    global qout_state

    #If the input is >= 5, change the state to 1 and return 2.
    if yrez >= 5:
        qout_state = 1
        return 2

    #If the input is <= 1, change the state to 0 and return 0.
    if yrez <= 1:
        qout_state = 0
        return 0

    #If the input doesn't make any of the previous statements true, use the stored state:
    #If the state is 1, it means that the previous input wasn't <= 1, so we are on "return 2" mode
    if qout_state == 1:
        return 2
    #If the state is 0, it means that the previous input wasn't >= 5, so we are on "return 0" mode
    if qout_state == 0:
        return 0
```

Visual representation:

[image]

Comment: This seems to have worked, thank you! Is it possible if applied a high Qout, that it has a sudden jump that results in yrez going from 5 to 0.5 let's say, even thought the borderline is 1?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that once yrez falls below 5, it will not the inner while loop. Calling the function another time does not continue at the last "return" but starts at the beginning of the function.

Not sure if it works, but you can try a callable class object instead of a function, which saves your local variable:

```
class Qout_class():

    condition = False

    def __call__(self, yrez):
        if (yrez >= 5):
            self.condition = True
        elif (yrez < 1):
            self.condition = False

        if self.condition:
            return 2.
        else:
            return 0.

Qout = Qout_class()
```

Comment: I get this error: __call__(self, yrez):
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry I had a mistake in the code (forgot the def and the yrez in the __call__ method), should work now